# Photoshop CC - Property Panel Always Shows No Properties

Tags: properties, panel, photoshop, nonetype

I have been slowly switching from Fireworks 6 to PS cc and have a unique issue I have not had before in any other Adobe product. My **Properties Panel** never shows any properties. No matter what I have selected, I never get any properties. 
[image]
I tried to select an image with the "Direct Selection" tool however that did not work either.

Is there a setting I am missing somewhere that I said to never show me this?

thanks for any help or advice

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties panel is mostly for Adjustment layers I believe. It isn't supposed to show anything in regards to selections. Create a new adjustment layer and you will see the properties panel populate.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks @TinMonkey! I think I was thinking more along the lines of this being Fireworks where you selected an object and it gave you all the properties that you could change.